# JavaFX: Keep window from being smaller than contained pane

Tags: javafx, layout

I have a VBox as the root node for a scene.  Each Pane inside has its own min-max height and I have them behaving the way I want.  I have the VBox set to completely fill the pane.

Two other things I want:

1. For the VBox to always fit the elements.  Stop shrinking when all elements are at their minimum and stop growing when they are at their maximum.
2. For the window to stop shrinking when the VBox does.

As it is, the window keeps shrinking and the VBox disappears into it as this happens.

It would be best to not have to specify a minimum height for the window as the size of these components may change.  I want that minimum height to be automatically calculated.  What's the most straightforward way to achieve that?

Here's my MWE:

```
package path.to.package;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Border;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderStroke;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderStrokeStyle;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderWidths;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LayoutTestApp extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Label labelA = new Label("Box A");
        Pane labelPaneA = new Pane(labelA);
        decoratePane(labelPaneA, 5, Color.TURQUOISE);
        labelPaneA.setMinHeight(20);
        labelPaneA.setMaxHeight(50);
        
        Label labelB = new Label("Box B");
        Pane labelPaneB = new Pane(labelB);
        decoratePane(labelPaneB, 5, Color.HOTPINK);
        labelPaneB.setMinHeight(30);
        labelPaneB.setMaxHeight(60);
       
        Label labelC = new Label("Box C");
        Pane labelPaneC = new Pane(labelC);
        decoratePane(labelPaneC, 5, Color.MAROON);
        labelPaneC.setMinHeight(20);
        labelPaneC.setMaxHeight(100);
        
        VBox root = new VBox(labelPaneA, labelPaneB, labelPaneC);
        decoratePane(root, 20, Color.BLACK);
        
        root.heightProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> {
            System.out.println("Root changed height to " + nv);
        });
        
        VBox.setVgrow(labelPaneA, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setVgrow(labelPaneB, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setVgrow(labelPaneC, Priority.ALWAYS);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        
        //Edited after it was explained that this isn't necessary
        //root.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
        //root.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
        
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
}

private static void decoratePane(Pane pane, double pw, Color color) {
    pane.setPadding(new Insets(pw, pw, pw, pw));
    pane.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(color, 
            BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, CornerRadii.EMPTY, BorderWidths.DEFAULT)));
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you binding the root's preferred size to the scene's size? What are you trying to achieve there?

Comment: I want the VBox to always fit the window.  I know there are multiple ways to achieve that, is there a better way?

Comment: The root of the scene always takes the dimensions of the scene.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Earlier I was resizing the window and the box wasn't changing until I added that line, but it's possible this was because its children weren't resizing, or I was simply mistaken.  Code edited, thanks!

Comment: I only see a huge hack here.

Comment: assuming the children actually have a min/max (!= -1), create bindings to their calculated sum and bind the stage's min/max to those bindings - or what do I overlook?

Answer (score 0):

This is a real hack; override the root node's `layoutChildren()` to update the stage's `minHeight` and `maxHeight`. Note also that a `VBox` doesn't constrain it's maximum height to the maximum height of its child nodes, so using a `VBox` you also need to override `computeMaxHeight(...)`:

```
    VBox root = new VBox(labelPaneA, labelPaneB, labelPaneC) {
        @Override
        protected void layoutChildren() {
            super.layoutChildren();
            Scene scene = getScene();
            if (scene == null) return ;
            Stage stage = (Stage) scene.getWindow();
            if (stage == null) return ;
            double heightDelta = stage.getHeight() - scene.getHeight() ;
            stage.setMinHeight(computeMinHeight(-1) + heightDelta);
            stage.setMaxHeight(computeMaxHeight(-1) + heightDelta);
        }
        
        @Override
        protected double computeMaxHeight(double width) {
            return getChildren().stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.summingDouble(node -> node.maxHeight(width)));
        }
    };
```

There must be a better way, though.

Comment: ehhh ... changing the window size during a layout pass is .. let's say suboptimal ;) What's wrong with binding (assuming the children really _have_ a min/max, that is `!-1` as in the OP's example) the window's min/max to the calculated sum of root childrens' min/max?